Translate ¬∃x (Pᵢ(x) ∧ Pⱼ(x)) where i <> j
A very basic question, predicate logic is not my forte.  A question about this equation was asked elsewhere. I'm just trying to understand what the equation means. Does it mean the following?
"There are no x's of which both i and j can be predicated to it."
Am I translating that correctly? If so, then the equation seems false, as even though "long" and "black" are not the same, a person's hair can be both long and black.  Or maybe the correct translation is,
"There exists a universe of x's in which i and j do not equal each other and in which i and j cannot both be predicated of x."  This isn't necessarily false, but the fact that that no hair in this universe is both long and black is not a result of the inequality of i and j.

In standard logic, any predicate can be predicated of any object, the result can be true or false. ¬∃x (Pᵢ(x) ∧ Pⱼ(x)) means that Pᵢ(x) and Pⱼ(x)  are never true for the same x simultaneously when i ≠ j. Whether this is true or false depends on what Pᵢ and Pⱼ are.

I see, so whether or not the proposition is true does not depend merely on the fact of i and j being unequal.  If i = "long" and j = "black," then the proposition would be false, but if i and j were contradictory, e.g., if i = "long" and j = "short," then the proposition would be true.

I suspect that i and j are subscripts.  P_i and P_j are different predicates in some set of predicates indexed on the integers or reals or some other set.  Pi(x) is "x + i = 2" satisfies your relation, for example.  If x + 2 = 2 then x + 3 is NOT 2, right?  In fact, if x + i = 2 for a given integer i, then x + j is not 2 for any other integer j, no matter what x is.  So, there does not exist an x such that Pi(x) and Pj(x).

@Him, are you saying the opposite of @Conifold?  Conifold is saying that the truth of the proposition depends on  what the predicates i and j are, but you are saying that as long as i and j are unequal, the proposition that there will never be an x of which both i and j can be predicated is always a true proposition.  Is that right?

I'm saying that neither i nor j are predicates.  P_i is a predicate.  i is just an index for some set of predicates P_something.  So, in my example, if i is 2, one would not say that "2 is a predicate".  However, x+i=2 is a bunch of predicates for x (one for each i).  Probably the authors could have more rigorously defined this proposition by making P a proposition with two variables.  For all i, j, if i neq j then ( there does not exist x such that ( P(i,x) and P(j,x) ).  However, maximum rigor in logic notation can get tiring, so they made i a subscript instead for some reason.

Let me rephrase.  Is the proposition--¬∃x (Pᵢ(x) ∧ Pⱼ(x)) where i <> j-- necessarily true or possibly true depending on the values of i and j?
